# Touchpad debugging - Opinion needed

Tags: 14.04, kernel, touchpad, lenovo, thinkpad

I'm trying to debug an odd touchpad problem with Ubuntu 14.04.4 on a Lenovo e460. I have followed this [touchpad debugging tutorial](http://%20However,%20if%20I%20connect%20a%20USB%20mouse,%20the%20mouse%20works%20fine.), but it doesn't directly address the symptoms I am experiencing.

Sometimes when I start the computer, the touchpad doesn't work at all. When this happens, "cat /proc/bus/input/devices" shows no entry at all for a touchpad/mouse/pointer. No matter how many times I restart, the result is the same. It is also the same for all three kernel versions I have installed (4.2.0-27, 4.2.0-35, and 4.3.6-040306). However, if I connect a USB mouse, the mouse works fine.

If I pull my single-boot Ubuntu SSD and reinstall the Windows hard drive that came with the computer, the touchpad works just fine in Windows. And, if I then put the Ubuntu SSD back into the computer and start Ubuntu, the touchpad starts working again.

This has happened twice in a month. It does not happen immediately after updates, other software changes, or changes to BIOS/UEFI configuration. And there are no touchpad/pointer-related settings in the BIOS/UEFI.

I am at a loss. Any ideas?